# Having Problem with $_get in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a page called list.php which retrieves from database and shows all the student names with their respective ids in a list. In raw php, this is how I have done this-

```
include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM marks ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
mysql_close();

if ($num > 0 ) {
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$studentname = mysql_result($result,$i,"studentname");
$studentid = mysql_result($result,$i,"studentid");  
?>
And then---

<a href="studentprofile.php?studentid=<? echo $studentid?>"><? echo $studentname ?></a>
<?
++$i; } } else { echo "No Record Found"; }

?>
```

When a user clicks on any of the student names, it takes the user to the page of that particular student and in that page I have a code like following-

```
include("connect.php");
$number = $_GET['studentid'];

$qP = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentid = '$number' ";
$rsP = mysql_query($qP);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rsP);
extract($row);
$studentid = trim($studentid);
$studentname = trim($studentname);
$studentgender = trim($studentgender);
```

The above code is working just fine. Now as far as I know $_get is disable in Codeigniter. But how to do the exact same thing that I mentioned above in codeigniter if $_get is disabled ? I went through some tutorials on alternative way of using $_get, but I didn't understand those well. Would you please kindly help? Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `$_GET` is discouraged in CI.

The simpliest way to rewrite that files is not using `$_GET`. Just add `method='post'` to your forms and tell your ajax requests to use post, if you have any. Use `$_POST` in PHP instead of `$_GET`.

If you are absolutely sure you need get requests passing parameters, you have to enable `query strings`. You can do it in your CI's config file:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

[See section 'Enabling query strings'](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) for details. But enabling `query strings` will cause `Url helper` and other helpers that generate URLs to malfunction.

So my suggestion is to use POST requests.

**UPDATE** Replace

```
<a href="studentprofile.php?studentid=<? echo $studentid?>"><? echo $studentname ?></a>
```

With

```
<a href="studentprofile.php?studentid=<? echo site_url("yourcontroller/studentprofile/$studentid")?>"><? echo $studentname ?></a>
```

Create method `studentprofile`:

```
<?php
class Yourcontroller extends CI_Controller {

public function studentprofile($id)
{
        include("connect.php");
        $number = $id;

        $qP = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentid = '$number' ";
        $rsP = mysql_query($qP);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($rsP);
        extract($row);
        $studentid = trim($studentid);
        $studentname = trim($studentname);
        $studentgender = trim($studentgender);
        // and so on...
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think probably you didn't get my point right. What I wanted to say was what to use instead of  this-" $number = $_GET['studentid'];    " And I should mention here.. I do not have any form in any two of my pages. please kindly check the code I submitted again. Thanks.

Comment: @user839685 I think you just aren't familiar with how CI sets things up. JOHN's answer is solid.  The link will looks like this: `<a href="/studentprofile/<? echo $studentid?>"><? echo $studentname ?></a>` then the $id in the above code will be the student ID you used to use $_GET for. Using $_GET isn't used much, it's usually POST ($this->input->post()) or the url parameters.

Comment: Actually, under John's setup, the link would be `<a href="/yourcontroller/studentprofile/<? echo $studentid?>"><? echo $studentname ?></a>`

Comment: @JOHN , You are the best. Thanks a lot for your help. @ Hans, I am new to CI and really not familiar with how CI sets things up. I am trying to learn it..:)